# Finding the equilibrium interest rate

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, gdp, interest-rate

Let's say there are only two countries in the entire world, Argentina and Chile, and there is free trade between them. The aggregated investments in both countries are $I^A$ and $I^C$ that are both exogenous variables. The saving is giving by
$S^A = A+ar$ where A,a> for Argentina and for Chile it is given by S^C that is an exogenous variable. I have to find the equilibrium interest rate.
My TA said it is the one that equates the total savings and the total investments in both countries.
$$S^A+S^C = I^A + I^C$$
$$A+ar+S^C = I^A + I^C$$
Solving for r we get
$$r = \frac{I^A+I^C-A-S^C}{a}$$
But my TA said this was wrong. What am I missing here?

Comment: In your final equation for r, it looks like you've divided by A rather than a. Could this be the error?

Comment: Of course! That must have been it, because I can't see any other error.

Comment: what assumptions you can make about I, I^C and S^C? are they exogenous?